# When I run FileZilla in Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10 I get this Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, filezilla

I am trying to upload some files from my desktop to my DigitalOcean droplet account, but in order to transfer the files I needed to install FileZilla to make the file transfer. After I installed the app on my Ubuntu 20.04 terminal in Windows 10 and run the command `filezilla` to launch the app it throws this error

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused ,14:44:20: 
Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

I know similar questions have been asked here, but I have tried all those solutions which didn't help in my case.

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` report in your terminal?

Comment: Yes when i run the echo DISPLAY it returns DISPLAY!@icarus

Comment: There is a dollar sign in the question I asked, which is important.

Comment: when i run echo $DISPLAY it return nothing in the terminal !@icarus

Comment: why would you need to install filezilla to make a file transfer?

Comment: Actually it's a web application that's in a folder on my desktop that am trying to host on digital ocean's droplet server which i would need to to upload through filezilla@MarcusMüller!

Comment: Ok, first of all, "Folders on Desktops" are probably not the best places to keep your application code. But I'm not the "folder police"... So. If it's on your desktop, why would you install FileZilla into a Ubuntu WSL machine? It's a program that's natively available for Windows.

Comment: Yes i have tried installing  the FileZilla windows but somehow it couldn't give me the configuration for the FTP and SFTP Configuration on windows that's why i had to install it on Ubuntu WSL!@MarcusMüller

Comment: The solution here is to correctly set up your filezilla, not to install a graphical tool in a VM.

Comment: Thank you i was able to resolve the issue!@MarcusMüller!